# Unexpected Python Pandas Pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I've been using Pandas for a while, but have the following issue I can't seem to resolve myself. I have the following dataframe (showing only top 5 of 12,263 items):

|  | Event Label | Total Events | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Access academic supports | 4 | 2020-11 |
| 1 | Access computers | 3 | 2020-11 |
| 2 | Buy books & supplies | 15 | 2020-11 |
| 3 | Find parking information | 2 | 2020-11 |
| 4 | Fund my one AT NAIT Card | 3 | 2020-11 |

The dataframe is created with the following call:

```py
tasks = tasks[["Event Label", "Total Events", "Month"]]
```

Then I pivot with the following code:

```py
p = tasks.pivot_table(index='Event Label', columns='Month', values=['Total Events'], aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

Instead of a table that shows the number of events by Event Label, with columns of months, what I get is a list of IP addresses. I have no idea where they come from!

| Event Label |
| --- |
| (not set) |
| 1.152.108.55 |
| 1.235.214.115 |
| 101.0.34.36 |
| 101.0.45.159 |

Maybe relevant: I'm running this in a Jupyter Lab page, though that's never been an issue for me before.

Comment: Please try: `tasks['Event Label'].eq('1.152.108.55').sum()` if it is greater than 0 the IP adresses are somwhere in your 12,263 items. And are showing on top because of alphanumerical ordering.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought of that, and is a big help!

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy coding!